# Connecting a desktop and I/O devices to guest VM

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, esxi, vsphere

I have several workstations that should host at most one VM at once. From my understanding vSphere only provides console access to each VM through a web interface, however I would like to display the UI (e.g. Windows UI, not the shell) of the OS on a monitor and connect a keyboard, mouse to the workstation for I/O.

Is there some way to access the running VM like described above? So far, I thought about using passthrough or a remote desktop, but I am still not sure if these solutions would work.

EDIT: VDI/VDA is not what I am searching for, as I do not want to access the OS remotely, but rather through a physical connection, e.g. by connecting a monitor with HDMI.

Comment: Can you clarify?  Are you running vSphere ESXi on the workstations or a central server? Are you trying to access the VMs from the workstations?  It sounds like you're talking about VDI/VDA (Virtual Desktops) which would require additional VMware software.

Comment: vSphere ESXi will be running on the workstations and I want to access the VM directly from the workstations, e.g. connect a monitor with VGA, HDMI, etc. I have never heard about VDI/VDA and it seems like this is exactly what I am searching for. Is VDI/VDA running as a type one hypervisor, since I require good performance for the running VM?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do that with ESXi.  There's no console access to run VMs with ESXi.  Its only a VM host, ESXi console is only for basic configuration of the host itself. To run & interact with VMs locally, you'll want Workstation if you stay with VMware.  Windows 10/Server 201x with Hyper-V will allow for local VM interaction, as will Linux with KVM.   VDA/VDI would entail you having a separate ESXi host and then you'd access your VMs via the workstation, or less powerful clients (check out VMware's Horizon).  Unfortunately, It's at least an order of magnitude more expensive.

Comment: I checked out VMware's Horizon and it actually seems very interesting. However, I did not find any reports about the performance, which is very important to me, as I plan to train neural networks in the VM. Do you have any experience with Horizon's performance? From my understanding so far, it also relies on ESXi and is therefore a type 1 hypervisor, and as such will have approximately the performance of a physical machine.

Comment: Yeah, VDI is not what you really need for what you want.  ESXi won't work if you want to work on the local console.  You'll need another hypervisor.